# Is there a way to extract User edit history of already edited cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I’m working with Google Sheets and need to extract the edit history of multiple cells in the same column. I’ve seen a lot of responses to this sort of query that extract the information when a cell is newly edited, does anyone know if the information can be extracted from past edits?

It would be ideal if the information could be extracted onto another Google Sheet or a cell in the same sheet, but it’s not a necessity so I am open to any suggestions! Have already given Selenium a go to scrape the information from the edit history window but was not able to specify specific cells to scrape the information for so came to a dead end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get cell edit history by Google App Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61693770/how-to-get-cell-edit-history-by-google-app-script)